# How To Install GNU Scientific Library in Windows 7

Tags: gnu, histogram

I am using CodeBlocks and I am trying to use one of the histogram functions that the GNU Scientific Library offers. However, I have no idea on how to install this library. My computer is running Windows 7 and CodeBlocks is using the GNU GCC Compiler.

Please advise!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into Cygwin (unix shell & tools for Winodws). You should be able to install CodeBlocks into it.